# Camera Pose Calibration: problem with multicam_capture_exec.py

Tags: ros, pose, camera-pose-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I'm trying to calibrate 2 home-made stereo cameras (4 total cameras) with the camera_pose toolkit and I've problems with the multicam_capture_exec.py.

I receive the following error:

```
Waiting for Server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py", line 43, in <module>
    from camera_pose_calibration.robot_measurement_cache import RobotMeasurementCache
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/robot_measurement_cache.py", line 34, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('pr2_calibration_executive')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 167, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 210, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 202, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: pr2_calibration_executive


[capture_exec-24] process has died [pid 12415, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py baseline12/left baseline12/right baseline6/left baseline6/right/ request_interval:=interval_filtered __name:=capture_exec __log:=/home/fabio/.ros/log/ad23e236-b07d-11e1-afbb-14dae9c3e9c0/capture_exec-24.log].
log file: /home/fabio/.ros/log/ad23e236-b07d-11e1-afbb-14dae9c3e9c0/capture_exec-24*.log
```

Any idea?

My launch file:

```
<launch>

<!-- MACHINES -->
  <machine name="rosboromir" address="rosboromir" user="fabio" env-loader="/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh">
  </machine>

  <machine name="rosfaramir" address="rosfaramir" user="fabio" env-loader="/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh">
  </machine>

<!-- LAUNCH BASELINE6 ON ROSBOROMIR -->
  <!-- Driver nodelet -->
  <node machine="rosboromir" ns="baseline6" name="stereo_image_proc_bsl6" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc"></node>
  <node machine="rosboromir" ns="baseline6" name="uvc_camera_bsl6" pkg="uvc_camera" type="stereo_node">
    <param name="left/device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="right/device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="fps" value="30" />
    <param name="skip_frames" value="3" />
    <param name="width" value="320" />
    <param name="height" value="240" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="baseline6" />
  </node>

<!-- LAUNCH BASELINE12 ON ROSFARAMIR -->
  <!-- Driver nodelet -->
  <node machine="rosfaramir" ns="baseline12" name="stereo_image_proc_bsl12" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc"></node>
  <node machine="rosfaramir" ns="baseline12" name="uvc_camera" pkg="uvc_camera" type="stereo_node">
    <param name="left/device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="right/device" value="/dev/video2" />
    <param name="fps" value="15" />
    <param name="skip_frames" value="1" />
    <param name="width" value="640" />
    <param name="height" value="480" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="baseline12" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

Command line for calibration:

```
roslaunch camera_pose_calibration calibrate_4_camera.launch camera1_ns:=baseline12/left camera2_ns:=baseline12/right camera3_ns:=baseline6/left camera4_ns:=baseline6/right/ checker_rows:=10 checker_cols:=5 checker_size:=0.0015
```

EDIT:
In the file calibrate_4_cameras.launch, the lines that give me the error are the following:

```
  <!-- generate robot measurements -->
  <node pkg="camera_pose_calibration" type="multicam_capture_exec.py" name="capture_exec" 
        args="$(arg camera1_ns) $(arg camera2_ns) $(arg camera3_ns) $(arg camera4_ns)" output="screen">
    <param name="cam_info_topic" value="camera_info" />
    <remap from="request_interval" to="interval_filtered" />
  </node>
```

Do I need that lines to have camera calibrated? What does they do?

EDIT2:
I've followed the stack trace and I've found that multicam_capture_exec.py calls robot_measurement.cache.py. At the line 34 it try to import a package that is not available:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('pr2_calibration_executive')
```

I've tryed to comment out that lines and the error goes away but I'm still not able to have some output to /tf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35898/camera-pose-calibration:-problem-with-multicam_capture_exec.py/) by [oleo80](https://answers.ros.org/users/2184/oleo80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, pr2_calibration has been split into two (slightly refactored) stacks: calibration and pr2_calibration. The pr2_calibration package always had its API marked "unstable", but it appears that this code was developed against the pr2_calibration_executive (which has gone away). You can find a (possibly updated) robot_measurement_cache.py in calibration_launch/src/calibration_executive.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-08**:
Did they ever solve this problem?  I'm trying to use camera_pose_calibration in Hydro with 3 Kinects and it's not going well.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-01-14**:
I'm not aware of anyone maintaining the camera_pose_calibration stack, so I very much doubt that it has been fixed.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-15**:
In that case, what method are people using for multiple Kinects to combine them in RViz?  I've looked all over and I can't find anything on the wiki or just by Googling.  And asking on here has been unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to the incorrect roslib.load_manifest, I found numerous \t's in the source that were basically keeping the pipeline from working, as well as several topics that didn't appear to be mapped properly.

My modifications can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/jbohren/camera_pose

I could get it to "work" with a couple kinects, but not with a calibrated stereo rig that I have. The resulting frame wasn't as good as I could do just by playing around with an interactive transform publisher.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1